# Do photons come out when electrons and holes recombine inside a forward biased diode?

Tags: pn-junction

When electrons fall to a lower level orbital they emit light/radiation at a particular frequency.

Is that the case for recombination?

My question came from this speech at the following part: https://youtu.be/Cdr89n_nf9Y?t=1639 which Im not sure I understood correct.

The lecturer gentleman in the video invented the point-contact transistor in 1947.

Comment: Apparently this film is a "1959 physics lecture" (the label appears on another film segment on ATT archive.)   Also, Brittain left Bell Labs in 1951, so this could be Harvard, or maybe U. Illinois.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Sometimes they do. That's called radiative recombination. There's other ways for electrons to lose energy and recombine with a hole. Those are the Shockley-Read-Hall (SRH) process and auger recombination.

SRH is recombination through atomic trap's in the lattice. These traps are caused by impurities or defects within the lattice which create intermediate bands within the band gap. This converts the electron/hole energy into phonons (lattice vibrations/heat).

Auger recombination is when an electron-hole pair interact with another carrier (an electron or a hole) which increases the energy level of the already free carrier. This extra energy for the carrier is then usually dissipated through through phonon interactions (i.e. heat again).

If your electron-hole pair avoids the other two types of recombination, then yes, you'll get light shining from it. That's how LED's work after all.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_generation_and_recombination) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In silicon devices (which make up well over 99% of the transistors and diodes made today), there is essentially no photon emission due to recombination.

This is because silicon is an *indirect gap* semiconductor. So an electron and hole can't directly recombine without violating conservation of momentum. In silicon, the dominant recombination mechanism is [*Shockley-Hall-Read recombination*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_generation_and_recombination#Shockley.E2.80.93Read.E2.80.93Hall_.28SRH.29_process), in which a *trap state* related to an impurity is used as an intermediate state to satisfy the momentum conservation condition.

Note: Shockley was Brattain's boss at Bell Labs when he and Bardeen discovered the transistor, and shared the Nobel with them.

In *direct gap* semiconductors, such as gallium arsenide or gallium arsenide phsphide, it is possible to have *radiative recombination*, and this is exactly how LEDs work. In some cases (for example, gallium arsenide), the light produced may be infrared or ultraviolet rather than visible.

> But what is he talking about when he shows the light via a microscope just after mentioning recombination ?

It would be good to know the date of the film, because there are two possibilites here:

- He's showing an LED, made from a direct gap material. But the first visible LED was not developed until 1962, 15 years after the point-contact transistor.
- He's showing a germanium (Ge) transistor. Ge is an indirect gap material but the difference between the minimum bandgap energy and the direct gap energy is not very large. This means that some electrons may be thermally excited into the direct gap states and produce noticeable radiative recombination even though most of the recombination going on is by the non-radiative SHR process. On the other hand the direct gap energy is 0.8 eV, corresponding to over 1.5 um emission wavelength, well away from visible --- the transistor would have to be running really hot to get visible light from this transition)

Comment: But what is he talking about when he shows the light via a microscope just after mentioning recombination ?

Comment: @user16307, where in the video?

Comment: 27:22. He's talking about LEDs which you've now mentioned.

Comment: @horta, I'm seeing the video as only 9:27 long.

Comment: Strange. 29:13 is when I see it end. Mb your browser is mucking up youtube?

Comment: @horta, Maybe I got jumped to the next video. Now I clicked again and got to the relevant part. It would be good to know the date of the film. The first visible LED wasn't developed until 1962. IIIRC germanium (the first transistor material) is indirect gap like Si, but with its low bandgap energy, it's possible that the barrier to the direct gap valley is low enough that there could be enough carriers excited there to cause a slight visible emission from a Ge diode.

Comment: @ThePhoton The video is from 1959

Comment: Okay, I'll guess then that the device is a silicon diode, running very hot. The direct-gap energy of Si is 2 eV, which corresponds to a nice visible wavelength of 619 nm. When very hot, a small fraction of the free carriers will be excited to higher band minima, and these would cause a small amount of radiative recombination.

Comment: It may be he was using SiC. Photoluminescence was discovered long before in 1907 it looks like. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode#History

Comment: @ThePhoton Brattain says that the mystery-crystal has a much larger bandgap, and has **visible transparency,** but he carefully avoids naming it (after already have displayed the two silicon and germanium boule crystals starting 21:40.)  Maybe it's some pre-publication research material (very first crude public demo of GaAs light emission?)

Comment: @wbeaty, Could be something like that, but not GaAs. GaAs gives 850 nm, not visible (and also GaAs is not transparent in the visible). And the first visible LED wasn't demonstrated until 3 years later. That was at GE, not Bell Labs, though I think lots of labs were on the same path.

Comment: @ThePhoton what's a visibly-transparent semiconductor from 1959?  It might not have been Brattain's own crystal, nor his microscope footage (perhaps loaned by other groups for lecture on semis?) Also, WP says Brattain left Bell Labs in 1951, so the film may have been Harvard or U. Illinois or other.  I wonder if the light output was actually NIR (seen up by monochrome film,) and he neglected mentioning?

Comment: @wbeaty, In general, emitting in the visible without absorbing in the visible seems very unlikely...But I didn't watch the whole video so I'm not sure exactly what words he used to describe it.

Comment: @ThePhoton Perhaps it's avalanche-light, as with Si visible-emitters, so not a modern LED. Brattain vid says: xtal is transparent because quantum (bandgap?) is in near-UV. Also, I notice hi-bright LEDs with xparent emitter dies. Get a recent 1w or 3watt SMD LED, examine die: green emitters appear to be pale green material. Hunt online... https://media.digikey.com/Photos/Avago%20Tech%20Photos/ASMT-MT00-00001.jpg  https://media.digikey.com/Photos/Avago%20Tech%20Photos/ASMT-AG00-NUV00.JPG  http://media.rs-online.com/t_large/R6935836-10.jpg  http://media.rs-online.com/t_large/F6961311-01.jpg

Comment: When an electron and hole recombine they emit a photon, even in indirect semiconductors (ignoring rare things like Auger recombination). The big difference for indirect semiconductors is that the recombination rate is much lower than direct semiconductors because it is a three particle process. It must be this way for conservation of energy to hold. Therefore the correct answer to the op's question is "yes"

Comment: @Matt, read the section I linked to in Wikipedia. In SHR recombination, energy is released as a phonon (lattice vibration energy quantum) not as a photon. Overall recombination rate must be enough to account for all the current passing through the diode, whether SHR, radiative, or Auger (described in the other answer), so the argument about recomb rate being lower in indirect gap materials makes no sense.

Comment: @ThePhoton Okay, I forgot how SRH recombination worked there for a minute. You are right about that. However, radiative recombination still happens just at a much lower rate due to the indirect bandgap. The answer is still yes. You can buy fancy cameras that can detect these photons, even in minuscule quantities, that are used in failure analysis.